# Use Spring Boot with explicitly configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to use Spring Boot so that all configurations are explicitly in the main class?

For example, is it possible to tell spring-boot to print all autoconfigurations make by @SpringBootApplication so that I can copy paste in my main class?

Or is it possible to copy then from somewhere into the main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing this. Either you embrace the devil and suffer the consequences latter if you need to personalize something unpredictable by spring boot developers or you don't use it's magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Spring Boot create a report (a list of auto configurations) simply by enabling debug mode in your **application.properties** file:

```
debug = true
```

The auto-configuration report contains information about the classes that Spring Boot found on the classpath and configured automatically. It also shows information about classes that are known to Spring Boot but were not found on the classpath.

And, because you've set `debug=true` in **application.properties** or **application.yml**, so you will see it in your output.

Comment: No, it just prints out which autoconfigurations where used, not how. I wanna change implicit configuration with explicit.